# WP Crowdfunding customization

Tags: plugins, woocommerce-offtopic

I am using WP Crowdfunding (w/ Woocommerce) to create a CF website.

I want to make some changes in the template that will affect all the campaigns (current and future) but I don't know how to proceed.

If I click on Inspect I can see the HTML file and do the changes there I want to, but I know that's only temporary. How can I make these changes permanently? I tried "What The File" but it gives me the theme template file, not the plugin one.

As you can see bellow, this is an example of a project. One thing that I want to do is replace the text box (for the amount) for a drop-down menu where backers can select the desired amount. But I have to access the correct PHP file to do that.

Can anyone help?

[image: Example of a CF project on my website]

Thank you very much!

Comment: WooCommerce uses plugin files as templates, but these can be copied into your theme (or child theme) and you can customize from there. You should read up on WooCommerce's documentation to locate particular files and/or contact the Crowdfunding plugin author for help identifying the files. They will be somewhere in your `/wp-content/plugins/` folder and you'll need to copy whichever file you're changing into a theme, not edit the file directly.